# Using proxy with Chromedriver within Google Cloud Engine

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use a proxy within Google Cloud Engine with chromedriver.

I've tried many solutions suggested (see below) but everytime the IP was the one on Google server.

Attempt 1:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

myproxy = '207.157.25.44:80'
prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
prox.http_proxy = myproxy
prox.ssl_proxy = myproxy

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, 
    executable_path="/user/sebastien/chromedriver", 
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")
get_location()
```

Attempt 2:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

myproxy = '207.157.25.44:80'
prefs = {}
prefs["network.proxy.type"] = 1
prefs["network.proxy.http"] = myproxy
prefs["network.proxy.ssl"] = myproxy

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, 
    executable_path="/user/sebastien/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")
get_location()
```

Attempt 3:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")

myproxy = '207.157.25.44:80'
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=http://%s" % myproxy)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,
    executable_path="/user/sebastien/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/")
get_location()
```

None of them would reach the website with the desired IP.

Again, this issue is happening when running the code on GCP Compute Engine, Canonical, Ubuntu, 16.04 LTS, amd64 xenial.

Below the function to test the IP:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

def get_location(ip=False):
    if ip:
        html = urlopen(f"http://ipinfo.io/{str(ip).split(':')[0]}/json")
    else:
        html = urlopen("http://ipinfo.io/json")

    data = json.loads(html.read().decode('utf-8'))
    IP = data['ip']
    org = data['org']
    city = data['city']
    country = data['country']
    region = data['region']

    print('IP detail')
    print('IP : {4} \nRegion : {1} \nCountry : {2} \nCity : {3} \nOrg : {0}'.format(org, region, country, city, IP))
```

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Did you try my suggestion about using a different proxy for this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think the issue that you're having is related to your code implementation.  I'm sure that the issue that you're having is related to your usage of a free proxy.  These type of proxies
are notorious for having connections issues, such as timeouts related to latency. Plus these sites can also be intermittent, which means that they can go down at anytime.  And sometimes these sites are being abused, so they can get blocked.

Your proxy is `207.157.25.44:80`, which is shown in the image below.

[image]

When I tested this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

proxy_server = '207.157.25.44:80'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy_server)

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.whatismyip.com/')
```

The Chrome browser opens, but it does not display any content.

[image]

If I check the address `207.157.25.44:80` via an online [proxy checker](https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-checker/) service, I get mixed results.

This image below shows that the proxy is not responding to any query types (HTTP, HTTPS, SOCKS4, SOCKS5).

[image]

When I do the same check 5 minutes later the proxy is up on HTTP, but has latency issues.

[image]

If I selected another proxy from the [free proxy website](http://free-proxy.cz/en/):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

proxy_server = '47.184.133.79:3128'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy_server)

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.whatismyip.com/')
```

I get a `CloudFlare` challenge page when connecting to the website `whatismyip.`

[image]

But if I try the same proxy on the website `nordvpn.com/what-is-my-ip` I get the proxy's IP address.

[image]

I would highly recommend testing any free proxy IP address multiple times to see if the address has any types of issues.  Additionally, you need to add some error handling in your code to catch issues when a proxy goes offline, because they can drop at anytime.

If you need to use a proxy, I would strongly recommend using a commercial proxy service, because they are more reliable than the free proxy services.

- [oxylabs.io](https://oxylabs.io/)
- [bright data](https://brightdata.com/)

Comment: Thanks, indeed it look like it was a matter of proxy than code. Took me a week to get an account at bright data so I couldn’t test before. Thanks!